# ApplePushNotificationAppDelegate.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I'm testing Push notifications using Xcode.
I have set up complete for App Development including Push Notifications Cert.
All looks good from here as far as I can tell.

My error occurs after pasting test code, in new project, from link below and building application.
http://mobiforge.com/design-development/programming-apple-push-notification-services

The Build error is: `ApplePushNotificationAppDelegate.h file not found`

How do I fix it?

Comment: #import "ApplePushNotificationAppDelegate.h"
#import "ApplePushNotificationViewController.h"

@implementation ApplePushNotificationAppDelegate

Comment: The tutorial you are using is a little outdated. Take a look at this APN tutorial from 2013. http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: You might also want to retrace each step you took to see if you missed anything. As user1554347 said, you might have just missed an import or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Is your appdelegate name is ApplePushNotificationAppDelegate? if so just check for that file in projet.  it is file missing problem only. if not check ur appdelegate is used else where if not used anywhere else comment out the import code.